# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous: x sizes: 60000 y sizes: 49000 Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

**I have a HDR project and I used python and mnist dataset
my code was working perfect until I tried to split the dataset I started to get this error which says ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:   x sizes: 60000   y sizes: 49000 Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

I am getting error in this line

```
m = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)
```

my code was working perfectly until I tried to split the dataset

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
DATASET_SIZE = 70000
TRAIN_RATIO = 0.7
VALIDATION_RATIO = 0
TEST_RATIO = 0.3

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()


X = np.concatenate([x_train, x_test])
y = np.concatenate([y_train, y_test])
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_val, y_val, test_size=0.3)
```

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback of the error you're hitting?

Comment: Please check the capitalization of your variables carefully. It is a terrible idea to use `x_train` and `X_train` in the same program for different things.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and added print statements to see the sizes of the train, test and val X and y data and there is nothing wrong with them. They have the values you would expect. See below

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
print (len(x_train), len(y_train),len(x_test), len(y_test) )
```

result is
60000 60000 10000 10000

```
X = np.concatenate([x_train, x_test])
y = np.concatenate([y_train, y_test])
print (len(X), len(y))
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
print (len(X_train), len(y_train),len(X_val), len(y_val))
X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_val, y_val, test_size=0.3)
print (len(X_val), len(y_val), len(X_test), len(y_test))
```

results are

```
70000 70000
49000 49000 21000 21000
14700 14700 6300 6300
```

These are what you should expect. You must have done something somewhere else in your code that made model.fit throw an error.